# LLVM: changing increment counter to use saturating increment

Tags: x86, llvm, instrumentation, llvm-clang

Clang has a built-in (marked experimental) method for adding simple code coverage counters. Just compile with `-fsanitize-coverage=inline-8bit-counters`.

Unfortunately the counters can wrap, sometimes unluckily to zero, making them not very trustworthy. I would like to change this to saturating counters, but I'm not very familiar with LLVM.

Currently, if compiling without optimization on x86-64, the instrumentation looks like:

```
mov    al, [counter]
add    al, 1
mov    [counter], al
```

or with optimization, it is able to obtain

```
add    byte ptr [counter], 1
```

What I'd like is for something like:

```
add    byte ptr [counter], 1
sbb    byte ptr [counter], 0
```

Or at least that is how I'd write it. Or maybe a single load and store is faster?

```
mov    al, [counter]
add    al, 1
sbb    al, 0
mov    [counter], al
```

Unfortunately I don't really understand LLVM, and am unsure how to translate this to LLVM instrumentation.

> Questions:
>    * It seems like I'd somehow need to tell it to subtract with flags, but how do I refer to the flags?
>    * Or is there an intrinsic saturating add?
>    * Or do I have to put in a conditional set to 0xff somehow and hope it is smart enough to optimize without putting in a conditional jump?

I have a feeling I'm not even in the right "mindset" for LLVM, and these questions are off base.  So I'd appreciate redirection if my questions themselves are 'wrong'.

---

For reference, here is what the current LLVM instrumentation looks like.

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Transforms/Instrumentation/SanitizerCoverage.cpp

```
if (Options.Inline8bitCounters) {
  auto CounterPtr = IRB.CreateGEP(
      Function8bitCounterArray,
      {ConstantInt::get(IntptrTy, 0), ConstantInt::get(IntptrTy, Idx)});
  auto Load = IRB.CreateLoad(CounterPtr);
  auto Inc = IRB.CreateAdd(Load, ConstantInt::get(Int8Ty, 1));
  auto Store = IRB.CreateStore(Inc, CounterPtr);
  SetNoSanitizeMetadata(Load);
  SetNoSanitizeMetadata(Store);
}
```

Comment: You want the resulting x86 asm to use `add al,1` / `sbb al,0` with load/store before / after.  Not two back-to-back memory-destination instructions; that would introduce an extra store/reload store-forwarding latency for this variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace the line

```
  auto Inc = IRB.CreateAdd(Load, ConstantInt::get(Int8Ty, 1));
```

with

```
  CallInst *AddOv = IRB.CreateBinaryIntrinsic(Intrinsic::uadd_with_overflow,
                       Load, ConstantInt::get(Int8Ty, 1));
  Value *SumWithOverflowBit = AddOv;
  auto Inc = IRB.CreateSub(
                IRB.CreateExtractValue(SumWithOverflowBit, 0),  /* sum */
                IRB.CreateZExt( /* convert from one bit type to 8 bits type */
                   IRB.CreateExtractValue(SumWithOverflowBit, 1) /* overflow */
                      , Int8Ty));
  SetNoSanitizeMetadata(AddOv);
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

LLVM IR doesn't have flags, or even variables. What you want is probably do add a comparison and a select before the store. [Compare `Load` against 255](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html#a103d309fa238e186311cbeb961b5bcf4), then [`select` either `Load` or `Inc` depending on the comparison](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html#abcd3995704196301af3e27cb4c93fd03), finally store the result of the `select` in the CreateStore.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and suggestion.  I tried that and it results in a conditional jump, even when compiling with -O3.  Is there a way to hint to LLVM what is going on?

Comment: No. LLVM takes its design seriously: IR really is intermediate, you cannot mix in any target stuff or use a little bit of target semantics like flags. The LLVM way to get rid of that conditional jump is to modify the backend to recognise that pattern and generate the code you want. I'm not familiar with that part though.

Comment: Okay, I'll try looking into that. I'm wading through the documentation now. Any suggestions on what I should be looking for? (even just good keywords to search?)

Comment: tablegen. Machine IR. And perhaps first of all, measure how well the currently generated code works compared to the code you want, and/or to how i32 counters work.